# How to calculate percentile rank of numpy array like in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame with 600 rows and 100 columns. I currently use this code to calculate rank in pandas:

```
df[rankCols].transform('rank', pct=True)
```

But I want to calculate it in numpy to improve speed. As I later convert my DataFrame to numpy array.

How to calculate the same in numpy? I can rank using argsort() but it does not calculate percentile rank.

Comment: Can you give us example data-frame and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve percentile rank by going one step further.

```
percentages = ranks / (data.shape[0] - 1)
```

Simply scaling the resulting ndarray from `argsort` seems to serve your purpose?

Comment: Thanks but It does not provide the same results as pandas. Check pr_kr's answer for dummy code.

Answer (score 0):

Creating percentile rank directly with Numpy can be complicated. However, you can try the following to see if it helps you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def percentile_rank(arr):
    sorted_indices = np.argsort(arr)
    sorted_rank = np.argsort(sorted_indices)
    percentile_rank = (sorted_rank + 1) / (len(sorted_rank))
    return percentile_rank

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(600, 100), columns=[f'col_{i}' for i in range(100)])

rankCols = df.columns

percentile_ranks = df[rankCols].apply(percentile_rank)
```

Comment: Hmm, it does not provide the same results as `percentile_ranks = df[rankCols].rank(pct=True)`

Comment: @user376285 Check answer's edit. As far as I tested, dividing by `len(df.shape[0])` rather than `len(df.shape[0])+1` provides the desired output.

Comment: @jlgarcia The edit you suggested here changes the behavior of the code. I rejected it in edit review because I don't know if the original author would agree with that edit. I think in this case, adding a comment (as you did) or posting a new answer is more appropriate than the edit.